# cmake - find_library - custom library location

Tags: c++, windows, cmake

I'm currently trying to get CMake running for my project (on windows). I want to use a custom location where all libraries are installed. To inform CMake about that path I tried to do that:

```
set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH D:/develop/cmake/libs)
```

But when I try to find the library with

```
find_library(CURL_LIBRARY NAMES curl curllib libcurl_imp curllib_static)
```

CMake can't find it.
When I set my prefix path to

```
set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH D:/develop/cmake/libs/curl)
```

... the library is located.

So my question is:
How can I configure CMake properly to work with a directory structore at a custom location which looks like that:

```
D:/develop/cmake/libs/
-> libA
   -> include
   -> lib
-> libB
   -> include
   -> lib
-> ...
   -> include
   -> lib
```

In "include" lie the public headers and in "lib" are the compiled libraries.

edit:
The current workaround for me is, to do this before i search for libraries:

```
set(CUSTOM_LIBRARY_PATH D:/develop/cmake/libs)
file(GLOB sub-dir ${CUSTOM_LIBRARY_PATH}/*)
foreach(dir ${sub-dir})
    if(IS_DIRECTORY ${dir})
        set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH ${CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH};${dir})
    endif()
endforeach()
```

But that way the default module for boost wont find it until it because the directory structore of boost is a bit different.

```
boost -> include -> boost-1_50 -> *.hpp
```

When I move the content if "boost-1_50" to "include" the library can be found but that way it's not possible to handle multiple versions right?

Comment: First, why are you setting CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH inside CMakeLists.txt? This will not work if another guy would try to compile your project.

Comment: It was only for testing - if it would work I would use an environment variable

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I saw that two people put that question to their favorites so I will try to answer the solution which works for me:
Instead of using find modules I'm writing configuration files for all libraries which are installed. Those files are extremly simple and can also be used to set non-standard variables. CMake will (at least on windows) search for those configuration files in

```
CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH/<<package_name>>-<<version>>/<<package_name>>-config.cmake
```

(which can be set through an environment variable).
So for example the boost configuration is in the path

```
CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH/boost-1_50/boost-config.cmake
```

In that configuration you can set variables. My config file for boost looks like that:

```
set(boost_INCLUDE_DIRS ${boost_DIR}/include)
set(boost_LIBRARY_DIR ${boost_DIR}/lib)
foreach(component ${boost_FIND_COMPONENTS}) 
    set(boost_LIBRARIES ${boost_LIBRARIES} debug ${boost_LIBRARY_DIR}/libboost_${component}-vc110-mt-gd-1_50.lib)
    set(boost_LIBRARIES ${boost_LIBRARIES} optimized ${boost_LIBRARY_DIR}/libboost_${component}-vc110-mt-1_50.lib)
endforeach()
add_definitions( -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0501 )
```

Pretty straight forward + it's possible to shrink the size of the config files even more when you write some helper functions. The only issue I have with this setup is that I havn't found a way to give config files a priority over find modules - so you need to remove the find modules.

Hope this this is helpful for other people.

Answer (score 43):

The simplest solution may be to add `HINTS` to each [`find_*`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.8/cmake.html#command%3afind_library) request.

For example:

```
find_library(CURL_LIBRARY
    NAMES curl curllib libcurl_imp curllib_static
    HINTS "${CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH}/curl/lib"
)
```

For Boost I would strongly recommend using the [*FindBoost*](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.8/cmake.html#module%3aFindBoost) standard module and setting the `BOOST_DIR` variable to point to your Boost libraries.

Comment: I do a combination of hints + environment variables like BOOST_DIR to help cmake find my libraries on windows. Also for some libraries if a standard module does not look at the environment variable I will check in my CMakeLists.txt if the environment variable is set but the CMake variable is empty and then set the CMake variable it expects to help it along.

Comment: The HINTS keyword did the task. In my case I am using the math library libm.so from a local folder. But everytime I compiled, it took it from the system folder. By using the HINTS keyword and stating the path of my libm.so, I could successfully link against my own libm.so.

Comment: And when I use this construction, in generated msvc project I get error "CURL_LIBRARY.lib not found".
I wounder why it tries to search library by variable name, but it do.

Answer (score 13):

Use CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH by adding multiple paths (separated by semicolons and **no white spaces**). You can set it as an environmental variable to avoid having absolute paths in your cmake configuration files

Notice that cmake will look for config file in any of the [following folders](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/find_package.html?highlight=find_package)
where  is any of the path in CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH  and name is the name of the library you are looking for

```
<prefix>/                                               (W)
<prefix>/(cmake|CMake)/                                 (W)
<prefix>/<name>*/                                       (W)
<prefix>/<name>*/(cmake|CMake)/                         (W)
<prefix>/(lib/<arch>|lib|share)/cmake/<name>*/          (U)
<prefix>/(lib/<arch>|lib|share)/<name>*/                (U)
<prefix>/(lib/<arch>|lib|share)/<name>*/(cmake|CMake)/  (U)
```

In your case you need to add to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH the following two paths:

```
D:/develop/cmake/libs/libA;D:/develop/cmake/libB
```

Answer (score 8):

You have one extra level of nesting.
CMAKE will search under `$CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH/include` for headers and `$CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH/libs` for libraries.

From CMAKE [documentation](http://www.cmake.org/Wiki/CMake_Useful_Variables):

> For each path in the CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH list, CMake will check
>   "PATH/include" and "PATH" when FIND_PATH() is called, "PATH/bin" and
>   "PATH" when FIND_PROGRAM() is called, and "PATH/lib and "PATH" when
>   FIND_LIBRARY() is called.

Answer (score 7):

There is no way to automatically set `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` in a way you want. I see following ways to solve this problem:

1. Put all libraries files in the same dir. That is, `include/` would contain headers for all libs, `lib/` - binaries, etc. FYI, this is common layout for most UNIX-like systems.
2. Set global environment variable `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` to `D:/develop/cmake/libs/libA;D:/develop/cmake/libs/libB;...`. When you run CMake, it would aautomatically pick up this env var and populate it's own `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH`.
3. Write a wrapper .bat script, which would call `cmake` command with `-D CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=...` argument.

Answer (score -2):

I've encountered a similar scenario. I solved it by adding in this following code just before `find_library()`:

```
set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH /the/custom/path/to/your/lib/)
```

then it can find the library location.

Comment: `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` is meant to be set by the user (or whoever calls `cmake`). Hardcoding it might work for you, but not on other systems.